# Filled map in Excel

Tags: excel, dictionary, charts

Filled map in Excel

Hello everyone,

I'm trying to add a map chart to my Excel report. I only have data for the locations listed below, but Excel is showing me all countries on the graph. That's why countries that include data are difficult to see clearly. For example, Czechia covers a small area on the map, making it difficult to see. I want only the data-containing continents to be shown on the map.

How can I see only the regions that are included?

- UK
- France
- Germany
- Czechia
- Turkey
- China
- South Korea
- Japan

I want to see the European and Asian continents on the chart. It's not necessary to show Africa and America.

One more thing; when I add datas (datas are include total amount to buy in 2023 as euro and they're 7 - 8 digits) to the map, some numbers don't fit and are hidden. How can I show all labels?

Excel version: 2019

I have tried to find solutions on the web, but I couldn't.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.